# Semiring between measure theory and abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, terminology

What is the relation between semirings in measure theory and semirings in abstract algebra?
Why are they called the same?

You can see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your title. Remember: the title is the very first thing people see of your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different. The name for the object in measure theory is inspired by the object in algebra, viewing $\cap$ as multiplication, $\cup$ as addition, $\emptyset$ as $0$ and $1$ is the union of all sets in $S$ (if this is an element of $S$ - the definition doesn't require that it is).

The difference is that it isn't necessarily closed under those operations, instead we have the condition that, if $A\in S$ and $B\in S$ then there exists a finite number of mutually disjoint sets $C_i \in S$ such that $A\setminus B = \cup_{i=1}^n C_i$.

Comment: The name of algebras and rings in measure theory is not only by analogy: they *are* rings with and without unit with respect to symmetric difference $A \mathbin{\Delta} B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)$ as addition and intersection as multiplication: they are [Boolean rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). The *semi* stands for relaxing a few of the properties as you write in your second paragraph.

Comment: In the case of algebras and rings, I agree, but isn't it the case that, for an $\textit{algebraic}$ semiring, one must have closure under both operations?

Comment: Sure, that's right and that's why there can't be a direct relationship (as one can see by considering the specific example of half-open intervals $[a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$). I was not objecting to your conclusion (as I tried to indicate in my last sentence). I was only mildly objecting to viewing $\cup$ as addition.

Answer (score 0):

The name in algebra comes from the fact that a semiring is a weakened form of a ring in which addition is an abelian semigroup rather than an abelian group.

The name in measure theory comes from looking at a generalization of a ring of sets.